# Can callback->InvokeAsync("", FB::variant_list_of(shared_from_this())(result)); throw a bad_weak_ptr exception?

Tags: c++, boost, firebreath

I was wondering is callback->InvokeAsync("", FB::variant_list_of(shared_from_this())(result)); can throw a bad_weak_ptr exception. Based on [this](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/12/firebreath-tips-asynchronous-javascript-calls/) and firebreath documentation,`callback` is a `JSObjectPtr` which defines an alias representing a `JSObject shared_ptr` and `shared_from_this()` is a method of `FB::JSAPI` that returns a `FB::JSAPIPtr` to the current object (also a `shared_pointer`). 
I have the following code used in a npapi plugin:

```
void MyClassAPI::MyFunction(const std::string& arg1,
                            const std::string& arg2,
                            const FB::JSObjectPtr & callback) try {

                            //some code here

                            callback->InvokeAsync("", FB::variant_list_of(shared_from_this())(result));

                            }catch(...){

                            //some code here

                            callback->InvokeAsync("", FB::variant_list_of(shared_from_this())(result));

                            }
```

which throws a: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >' what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr   when I am in a browser's tab and close it before function finishes its execution.` and I can't really understand where this exception comes from.

Comment: is your object already stored in some `shared_ptr` prior to calling `shared_from_this()` ?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I didn't mention that this exception is thrown only when I am in a browser's tab and close it before function finishes its execution

Comment: who owns the shared_ptr? Can you show enough code to describe how the ownership is managed? Because, enable_shared_from_this does not imply that the object stays around when a method is executing. Usually, you use functor _bound to_ a shared_ptr _as the callback_. It looks like you were trying to avoid this, but that implies no one is holding the shared reference, at least not in the code shown

Comment: I have a npapi plugin based on Firebreath framework. 
When plugin is initialized MyClass creates a JSAPI object through function: 
`FB::JSAPIPtr MyClass::createJSAPI() { 
FB::JSAPIPtr myshared_ptr= boost::make_shared<MyClassAPI>(FB::ptr_cast<Codebendercc>(shared_from_this(‌​)), m_host); 
return myshared_ptr; }`

Comment: Then in MyClassAPI I have MyInitialFunction which creates a new thread in order to run MyFunction:

Comment: FB::variant MyClassAPI::MyInitialFunction(const std::string& arg1, const std::string& arg2, const FB::JSObjectPtr & callback) try { // code here boost::thread* t = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClassAPI::MyFunction, this, var1, var2, callback)); return; }catch (...) { return;}

Comment: After the new thread is created MyClassAPI::MyFunction starts its execution. If I close the tab before MyClassAPI::MyFunction is created a bad_weak_ptr exception is thrown. I know how to solve it, my question is how bad_weak_ptr exception is thrown from shared_ptr pointers.